# Raphael- generate path based on clicks

Tags: javascript, raphael

I have to generate several complicated paths, and I'm looking a way to make it easier. I found http://ianli.com/sketchpad/ but it generates 'hand drawing' path and I need something like this:
I click on point A, then on point B and in result I'll get path coordinates(M and L) from A to B.

Do u know any tool, which could help me?

Comment: There's svg-edit, but sounds like a staightforward thing you could write yourself if you just need the points.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple function called by the mouse click. Using a timer event, you could then store the mouse coordinates to an array (or even a json object or xml file) at given intervals. Each time the timer event is triggered, you would use a raphael function to draw a straight line between the current point and the previous one. When the user has finished drawing the line, you could write a function that analyzes the distribution of coordinates in the array and performs some smoothing using bezier curves.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with raphael. Here is a quick (but dirty) solution how one could implement it:

http://jsfiddle.net/y543x/1/

```
rect.click(function (e) {
 ...
    alert("M"+lastClickX +"," + lastClickY + "L"+currentClickX+","+currentClickY);
 ...
}
```

It is just a simple rectangle which reads the coordinates from the click event and puts these
into a string. No magic. Hope this could help you.